# How to select the min and max date from a table into another table on the same row? in SQL

Tags: sql

So I have an example of a table like below:

| ID | Category | AdmissionDate | DischargeDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | A | 2017-07-20 | 2017-07-21 |
| A1 | B | 2017-07-27 | 2017-07-28 |

I would like to select the Min and Max date and also create two new columns based on the min and max date as below:

| ID | MinAdmissionDate | MaxDischargeDate | AdmittedCategory | DischargeCategory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2017-07-20 | 2017-07-28 | A | B |

The admitted category would be based on the MinAdmissionDate while the dischargeCategory would be based on the MaxDischargeDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try joining to grouped table:

```
select
    grouped.ID,
    grouped.AdmissionDate,
    grouped.DischargeDate,
    admission.Category admissionCategory,
    discharge.Category dischargeCategory
from 
(
    select
        ID,
        min(AdmissionDate) AdmissionDate,
        max(DischargeDate) DischargeDate
    from testTable
    group by ID
) [grouped]
left join testTable [admission] on
    [grouped].ID = [admission].ID and 
    [grouped].AdmissionDate = [admission].AdmissionDate
left join testTable [discharge] on
    [grouped].ID = [discharge].ID and 
    [grouped].DischargeDate = [discharge].DischargeDate
```

[Database fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bbf775/4).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```sql
WITH cte As
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        Category,
        AdmissionDate,
        DischargeDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY AdmissionDate) As ARN,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DischargeDate DESC) As DRN
    FROM
        YourTable
)
SELECT
    A.ID,
    A.AdmissionDate As MinAdmissionDate,
    D.DischargeDate As MaxDischargeDate,
    A.Category As AdmittedCategory,
    D.Category As DischargeCategory
FROM
    cte As A
    INNER JOIN cte As D
    ON D.ID = A.ID
    And A.ARN = 1
    And D.DRN = 1
;
```

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/38c10/2/0)
[ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql)